# Can I mine on my private blockchain using geth with rpc?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, mining, json-rpc

I am using the web3 api and want to try out mining using rpc.
The usual **miner.start()** (which is used on terminal) does not work even after including the miner api when starting geth and I get the following error.

> Error: Cannot read property start of undefined.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please share exact code.

Comment: I have a web3 instance

and have written 
var mine = web3.miner.start();

Answer (score 1):

try to load geth with the miner module:

e.g : `--ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,personal,web3"`

Comment: You might need need `--rpcapi` instead, if it's over RPC.

Comment: tried that still not working.

This is what I wrote

geth --rpc  --rpcapi web3,eth,net,personal,miner,admin,debug--rpcaddr="localhost" --rpcport="8545" --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:8545" console

Comment: try geth --rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --ipcapi "admin,eth,debug,personal,web3,miner"

Comment: Tried this but still no result.

Answer (score 1):

Web3 is not exposing a miner object as its own. [Refer here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3js-api-reference)

You can do this from `ipc` socket with help of javascript.

- Save the function as a file `mine.js`
- Load the script into `ipc` console using `loadScript('YOURPATH/mine.js');`
- Make sure you have necessary modules loaded. `geth --rpc --rpcapi web3,eth,net,personal,miner,admin,debug--rpcaddr="localhost" --rpcport="8545" --rpccorsdomain="localhost:8545" console`

**An example would be**

```
/*
 * Mine when there are transactions!
 */

var mining_threads = 1

function checkWork() {
  if (eth.getBlock("pending").transactions.length > 0) {
    if (eth.mining) return;
    console.log("== Pending transactions! Mining...");
    miner.start(mining_threads);
  } else {
    miner.stop(0);  // This param means nothing
    console.log("== No transactions! Mining stopped.");
  }
}

eth.filter("latest", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });
eth.filter("pending", function(err, block) { checkWork(); });

checkWork();
```

You can refer more [ethereum utility snippets](https://lightrains.com/blogs/useful-ethereum-geth-javascript-snippets)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I cannot understand how to use such a script. Please explain how this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used an extended web3 module.
Used npm install web3admin and then in my server code wrote web3Admin.extend(web3).
This allows me to use the miner api.